# Selecting elements with javascript returns an empty array

Tags: javascript

I have to approve forum members based on their ip addresses. To ease how much manual work I have to do, I wanted to pull the ip addresses from the html and run a script with them. I figured I'd use javascript to pull the data I need.

In the javascript console on Chrome, I run

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td')
```

and I just get an empty array back even though there are plenty of td elements on the page. Other javascript appears to work. So what gives?

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: And did you run that code after the elements in the DOM

Comment: I'm running the code from my js console.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code inside `window.onload = function(){ *code here* };`